# is this the right way to update a record in dynamoDB

Tags: node.js, express, serverless

I am trying to add/update a record in a dynamoDb i am sure that this method will add a record, but i am really confused wether it will update if the record is in place or need to write a separate update method

```
const lookUpTableModel = require('../src/modelGenerator');

    const { LookUpTable } = lookUpTableModel({ table: personLookUpTable, entity: 'PersonLookUP' });
    
    const item = {
      neo4jkey: personObj.key,
      saleforceId: body.Id,
    };
    LookUpTable.put(item);
```

if not this method helps in update please guide me.

Comment: You try it to clear your confusions.

Comment: @hoangdv this is a serverless application and i can not run and check locally .

Comment: actually, you can run and try it on your local side if your function just works with dynamodb (local).  For your question, the put method will update (override) your record if the partition key has existed.